# Faking a usb device on chrome

Tags: google-chrome, usb

I am doing a security course at university and I am trying to solve a challenge where a website (only works on chrome) is trying to access one of my usb devices. If I try to connect my camera, a HTTP request with this payload is send :
`{product_name: "HD WebCam", manufacturer_name: "Generic"}`

Now I want to create a "fake usb device" where I can decide myself what procut_name and manufacturer_name are. Is there a way of doing that in chrome or do I need to create a virtual usb device on my machine?

Comment: Your question made me very curios. The [docs](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_usb) do not seem to mention about mocking USB devices and I cannot see anything related to this in the Chrome developer tools. I guess you will have to create a virtual USB device on your machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Alexei is right, the usb device, hard disk, CD/DVD drive doesn't belong to the browser, but you can emulate a real device on your windows (assuming you're using windows).

Maybe this site can help you: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/usbcon/writing-a-ude-client-driver

or this one: [USB Emulation In Python With No Additional Hardware](https://github.com/smulikHakipod/USB-Emulation)

or download the [USB/IP PROJECT](http://usbip.sourceforge.net/#download)